# How to check if native code is being triggered in a React Native Project

Tags: react-native-ios

I am building a React Native Application. I don't have any background in native iOS or Android, so the native code parts are very confusing to me.

Right now, I have to determine if a specific line of code in the 'AppDelegate.m' file is being triggered when the notification arrives. But my lack of knowledge in Objective-C and Xcode prevents me from doing so.

How do I check if a specific line of code is being triggered in the native iOS code?

Answer (score 0):

You can you the breakpoint debugging system thats in both Android Studio and Xcode. You will need to put a breakpoint on the line of code that you want the IDE to stop on when it is run.

Android Studio

https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/

Xcode

[https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/debugging_tools.html]